# How to remove C/C++ perspective from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Some time ago I used Eclipse for C++ development (Linux). Later I uninstalled Eclipse, and then installed it again for Java development. List of available perspectives still contains C/C++ perspective, which is not used. How can I delete this perspective from the list?

Note: Windows - Preferences - Perspectives - C/C++ - Delete doesn't work (Delete button is disabled). Maybe I need to uninstall something else? In any case, I don't need anything related to C/C++ in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall [CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) (Eclipse's plugin for C/C++ development).

Comment: How exactly? I don't see CDT Linux package, maybe this should be done inside of Eclipse itself? Anyway, I don't know exactly how to do this, and don't know whether CDT is installed...

Answer (score 1):

From [Eclipse CDT Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_uninstall_CDT.3F):

1. Shutdown the eclipse shell that is running CDT
2. Remove the CDT plugins

   - Navigate to the directory where the CDT plugins are installed (typically eclipse/plugins)
   - Remove the following plugins:

     - org.eclipse.cdt.*
3. Remove the CDT metadata

   - Navigate to the workspace/.metadata/.plugins directory
   - Remove the following directories (if they exist):

     - org.eclipse.cdt.*
4. Restart Eclipse